# Copy Item from a list to another with resizable elements jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement a Template creation page.

On the side of the page are elements that you can choose from and on the other side there is a box where you can drop (and copy) elements and resize them.

This produce a full form created by the user and saved into a DB. The code I'm using rely on the **jQuery** List and drag and drop code.

When I drag one element from the first list into the box (second list) the list item get copy and resize fine. The second time and any time after I try to drag and drop the item (that have been clone), it doesn't resize.

I have research and didn't find a solution where the copyhelper create a resizable clone.

In the browser, the code says that all new element are in my resizable class.

I'm using this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $("#sortable1").sortable({
            connectWith: ".connSort",
            helper: function (e, li) {

                this.copyHelper = li.clone().insertAfter(li);
                // Copy helper ne retourne pas les propriete resizable

                $(this).data('copied', false);
                var lis = li.clone();
                return lis
            },

            stop: function () {

            var copied = $(this).data('copied');

            if (!copied) {
            this.copyHelper.remove();
            }

            this.copyHelper = null;
            }
        }).disableSelection();
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#sortable2").sortable({
            receive: function (e, ui) {
            ui.sender.data('copied', true);
            }
        })
    });

    $(function () {
        $(".osizer").resizable({ grid: 25 })
    });

});



</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
     <div style="width:20%;float:left">
        <div style="width:100%; height:100%">
            <ul id="sortable1" class="connSort">
                <li class="ui-state-default osizer"> Vide </li>
                @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables["Champs"].Rows)
                {
                    <li class="ui-state-default osizer"> @row["Nom"]  
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="width:80% ; height:80%; float:right ; border:1px solid black">
        <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:100%">
            <ul id="sortable2" class="connSort" style="width:100%; height:100%"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ($) {


        $(function () {

            $("#sortable1 li").draggable({
                connectToSortable: '#sortable2',
                helper: 'clone'

            });

            $('#sortable2').sortable({
                out: function (e, ui) {
                    $('#sortable2').children().resizable({
                        minHeight: '10',
                        containement: '#sortable2',
                        resize: function (e, ui) {
                            (ui.helper).css({ position: 'relative', left: '0', top: '0' })
                        }
                    })
                }
            });

            $('ul,li').disableSelection();

        });
    });



</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body style="height:800px;padding:30px;">

<div style="width:100%;height:800px">

            <ul id ="sortable1" style="width:20%;float:left">
                <li class="ui-state-default osizer"> Vide </li>
                @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables["Champs"].Rows)
        {
                    <li class="ui-state-default osizer"> @row["Nom"] - @row["DeType"]</li>
                }
            </ul>
    <ul id ="sortable2" style="width:80% ; height:80%; float:right ; border:1px solid black" ></ul>
</div>

</body>
```